# Question DriveApp (Google Apps Script) off-topic

Tags: support, vote-to-close

I've flagged **[this question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/61333/29140)** as off-topic a while  ago, only to realize that it is still active. Tried to find the question in the close review history, without success, to see who has done what (and when):

[image]

Why isn't this question closed as off-topic? Where to find the question in the review history?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The votes have aged away. As per [Meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/204327/when-are-moderator-flags-automatically-dismissed-as-aged-away-by-the-system).

> Certain flags and votes are invalidated if they are of sufficient age.
> The rules have changed over time, but currently they are:
>
> [...]
>
> #### The most recent Close or Reopen vote on a post:
>
> - if the vote is older than 4 days
> - and
>
>   - the question has >= 100 views
>   - or there have been no new votes (of the same type) since
>   - or it's been dequeued from review with a disagreeing result (leave closed in reopen, or do not close in close)

In this case, the question was dequeued from the close queue by jonsca [choosing to keep it open](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/review/close/38007)

Comment: I thought it was okay, but if there's a consensus to close it, that's fine with me.

Comment: @jonsca Well, Alex, JohnC and myself voted to close. GAS used in GSheets, GDocuments, Gpresentation, GForms is ontopic.

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra The question has been migrated to SO, as I thought that was the best place for it.

Comment: @jonsca Yeah, noticed it, thanks for that.